# why i got error while creating first react project

Tags: reactjs

C:\Users\Admin\OneDrive\Desktop\React Project>npm -v
'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
10.2.4
solve this error guys

Comment: Hello.  What command did you run?  Did you install Node properly?  Which version of Node did you install?

Comment: C:\Users\Admin>node -v
v20.11.0

C:\Users\Admin>npm -v
'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
10.2.4

i got like this

Comment: Iam using 20.11.0 version for node js and 10.2.4 for npm pls rectify my issue

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First run the command to find out your node version in your system:

```
node -v
```

You also need to check your npm installation using:

```
npm -v
```

Also update if they are not on the latest versions. And create a project again:

```
npx create-react-app demo-project
```

Let me know how it works for you.

Comment: i got like this if i command above line 

C:\Users\Admin>node -v
v20.11.0

C:\Users\Admin>npm -v

'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
10.2.4

C:\Users\Admin>

Comment: could u pls give solution

Comment: As alternative to create-react-app, in so readers know there are choices:  `npm create vite@latest -- --template react`

Comment: can i use CRA instead of vite

Comment: Do one thing. Unistall node and npm. Then make sure by checking if they are completely removed with all dependencies from C drive/programs. Then reinstall the latest versions for both. Make sure you are installing the stable versions.

Comment: yeah i will do it

Comment: C:\Users\Admin\OneDrive\Desktop\React>npx create-react-app login
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\Windows\system32
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Admin\OneDrive\Desktop\React
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent spawn C:\Windows\system32 ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-02-21T07_12_15_350Z-debug-0.log